# Creating a child CWnd inside a CView paint corruption

Tags: c++, background, mfc, window, view

I want to create a CWnd derived class inside a CView derived class. I am using also a window splitter to create a tree control menu to the left side and a view area in the right side like the draft below.

```
   ------------------------
   | tree  | View         |  
   | menu  |              |
   |       |              |
   ------------------------
```

The problem is that when `CWnd::OnEraseBkgnd` is called for the 1st time it erases the background from the Window's most top left corner instead of the view's client area causing a temporary corrupted area. I tried to use the `SetWindowPos` but didn't solve the problem.

I create the CWnd derived class like this

```
CRect rect;
m_MediaWindow->GetClientRect(&rect); //Get CSplitterView client area size 



if (!m_videoChildWnd.Create(NULL, NULL,  WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE , rect, m_MediaWindow,  ID_DSHOW_RENDER_WND)) {
       // failed to create child       

        return TRUE;
}

::SetWindowPos(m_videoChildWnd,NULL, rect.left, rect.top, rect.Width(), rect.Height(),
                SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOOWNERZORDER | SWP_FRAMECHANGED);

m_videoChildWnd.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
```

Now inside m_videoChildWnd exist the `OnEraseBkgnd` function

```
BOOL CWndVideoChild::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC) {
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default

    CBrush brush;
    CRect rect;


    GetClientRect(&rect);
    brush.CreateStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);   
    pDC->FillRect(rect,&brush);

    return TRUE;
}
```

after almost 3 calls from the framework the repaint system restore the corrupted area and everything works just fine.

Any ideas how to solve this ?

Comment: Try to remove `WS_VISIBLE` style, you are calling `ShowWindow()` anyway. How do you register a class for that window? Does it have CS_OWNDC?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I removed already the ShowWindow. No I did not register the window. And it does not have the CS_OWNDC. Can you show me how ?

Comment: I updated the code but I have the same results.

CString className = AfxRegisterWndClass(CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC, NULL, (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH), NULL);

 if (!m_videoChildWnd.Create(_T(className), NULL,  WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE , rect, m_MediaWindow,  ID_DSHOW_RENDER_WND)) {
..................

Comment: (1) Are you saying that your `pDC->FillRect(rect,&brush);` paints outside the client area of the parent window? (2) At what point do you call `m_MediaWindow->GetClientRect(&rect);`? Is that `m_MediaWindow` fully constructed?

Comment: (1) yes that"s what I mean. (2) at the cview::initialUpdate. At this point I even tried to post a custom message for the cwnd creation. It failed too. At the creation moment I have no problem but when cview that hosts cwnd is shown on the screen for the first time  then automatically is called the cwnd::onEraseBkgnd that paint outside of the client area and specifically begging at the left most corner and after. The problem is dissappearing when cview::onsize called for the 1st time. After that, the cwnd::onEraseBkgnd paint just fine and no problem again until I exit and restart the app.

Comment: I am trying to understand the hierarchy of your windows. Is it MDI or SDI? Is `m_MediaWindow` a view? Who is the splitter?

Comment: Hi Vlad.. yes its an SDI application. I am using a derived CView class to show my videos inside which I named CSplitterView. CSplitterView inside the initialUpdate calls a generic video class that determines which video interface (MCI or DShow) to use. Inside this generic video class I create a new CWnd that represent the video rectangle. The m_MediaWindow is the original CSplitterView that is the parent of the new CWnd. I hope you understand now the situation.

Comment: If you are in the `m_MediaWindow`'s `OnInitialUpdate()`, why do you refer to it as `m_MediaWindow` instead of `this`? Are you possibly calling that `m_videoChildWnd.Create()` from somewhere else? From where?

Comment: Hi Vlad, CSplitterView::OnInitialUpdate CALLS a generic video class named CVideo,  passing its own window handle as a parameter to this video class. Now, inside the CVideo, the CSplitterView is called m_MediaWindow (passed before as a parameter), and from there I create the the CWnd derived class that is called m_VideoChildWnd. All this story is done because the generic video class CVideo, determines what video interface to use in realtime. It creates the extra CWnd only in Direct Show interface. In MCI interface this window is never created.

Comment: Vlad, problem solved. Thank you for your time. 
The root of the problem was the "view" switching and had nothing to do with the child CWnd creation. I have 4 views (CView derived classes) that are swiching depending of the content. At the swiching time I used at the very begging the ShowWindow(SW_SHOW) for that "new" view without RecalcLayout and Position the view before. Best Regards !!!